# fclose() then free()?

Tags: c, file, memory, free, fclose

Assume I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

    fclose (pFile);
    //This never happens: free(pFile)
    return 0;
}
```

I have never seen a program which does `free(pFile)` after closing the file handle. Why is that?

I know that since `fclose()` doesn't receive a pointer to `pFile`, then it doesn't actually free the pointer's memory. I was under the impression that pointers should always have their memory freed if they are pointing to dynamically allocated memory. Why doesn't anyone `free()` the file pointer?

Comment: "Why doesn't anyone `free()` the file pointer?" - because it would be plain wrong.

Comment: `free()` doesn't receive a pointer to its argument either.

Comment: first, you do NOT want to be calling free on the file descriptor table (where the FILE * points is to some entry in that table) second, you only call free() on a pointer that was set by one of the malloc() family of functions (certain functions, like dup() use malloc in the background, so the resulting pointer needs to be free'd)

Comment: When you pass pFile to fclose, you're passing a FILE*. So fclose certainly could call free on it, and it would have the same effect as if you did this yourself. However what actually happens is more complicated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`free` is called in response to `malloc` to return allocated memory.  `fopen` likely indeed does do some mallocing, but the act of closing the handle (`fclose`) is, by design, going to clean up everything `fopen` did.  The contract you have with `fopen` is that closing the handle will free all outstanding resources.

The general rule of thumb is for every `alloc` have a `free`. If you call a function which does an `alloc`, it's description should warn you of what the caller is responsible for freeing.

Long story short, `fclose` will clean up any resources created by `fopen`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I never found a conclusive answer to that anywhere!

Answer (score 5):

Memory allocation of the `fopen` function is implementation dependent (per CRT). You can be sure that `fclose` is always implemented to free all the memory that `fopen` allocated.

Answer (score 1):

fclose() will release the related resources. 
However, when you finish executing the command fclose(fp); , the fp is still not NULL. 
Hence, you need to assign NULL to it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When closing the file more than once, `fclose` returns 0 the first time, but -1 thereafter.

Therefore, it probably takes care of it in a smart way.

At least this is the case in Windows, please correct me if I'm wrong.